# MegaCli create virtual drive from new disk (is it dangerous for the existing array?)

Tags: raid, megaraid, megacli

This is a linux system with a MegaRaid controller. MegaCli is installed. 
I currently have:

```
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-6, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 25.466 TB
...

Virtual Drive: 1 (Target Id: 1)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 223.062 GB
...

Virtual Drive: 2 (Target Id: 2)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 118.718 GB
...

Virtual Drive: 3 (Target Id: 3)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 111.281 GB
...
```

Now I would like to create another VD with a new disk that has been put in the system, but I don't want to have to put the server offline to do it via the MegaRaid tool/bios. I can do

```
megacli -CfgLdAdd -r0 [4:0] -a0
```

where 4 is the enclosure device ID and 0 is the slot number, and this should do the job just fine. However I am concerned with how it will affect the existing arrays and VDs. The 25TB array should remain untouched and I am simply concerned if creating the new VD from the new physical disk is safe to do, or am I risking the existing setup and, even worse, risking the data?

Will I be fine running the above command on the live system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LV - Logical Volume
>
> PD - Physical Disk

I did same thing multiple times with active raid1 LV built from two disk within. **No data lose** as a result. Moreover megacli will **refuse** to add new LV when PD is used in other LV.

Answer (score 0):

Space out multiple VD add/delete operations on a given host by 60 seconds, as each locks up the HBA for a short time, and you don't want that to happen back to back.

Also, why are you still using megacli when storcli is available?